# What does `PUSH 0xFFFFFFFF` mean in a function prologue?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to understand assembly code through a book called "Reverse Engineering for Beginners" [[LINK]](http://beginners.re/). There was a piece of code win-32 assembly code I didn't quite understand.

```
main:
    push 0xFFFFFFFF
    call MessageBeep
    xor  eax,eax
    retn
```

What does the first `PUSH` instruction do?? Why is it pushing 0xFFFFFFFF to the stack, but never popping it back again? What is the significance of 0xFFFFFFFF?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible that the calling convention used in this case has the callee clean up the stack.

Comment: The [documentation for `MessageBeep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356(v=vs.85).aspx) will tell you what the value pushed is for. Probably worth the effort to read it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/x86/3261/calling-conventions#t=201608201329248988454

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are looking at the equivalent code for

```
int main() {
    MessageBeep(0xffffffff);
    return 0;
}
```

The assembly code actually don't contain any prolongue or epilogue, since this function doesn't make use of the stack or clobber any preserved register, it just has to perform a function call and return 0 (which is put in `eax` at the end). It *may* be receiving arguments it doesn't use as long as it uses the cdecl calling convention (where the caller is responsible for arguments cleanup).

[`MessageBeep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356.aspx), as almost all Win32 APIs, uses the [stdcall calling convention](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Callee_clean-up) (you'll find it in the C declarations hidden behind the `WINAPI` macro), which means that it's the called function who is responsible for the cleaning up of the stack from the parameters.

Your code pushes `0xFFFFFFFF` as the only argument to `MessageBeep`, and calls it. `MessageBeep` does his things, and at the end ensures that all its arguments are popped from the stack before returning (actually, there's a special form of the `ret` instruction for this). When your code regains control, the stack is as before you pushed the arguments.

Comment: Thanks!! I get it now :)